# How to click within the textbox with no unique identifier as per the html through selenium-webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

```html
<div class="panel">
      <div data-bind="foreach: UriParameters">
        <div>
          <input readonly="true" spellcheck="false" tabindex="100" class="uriParameterLabel" data-bind="value: '{' + name + '}'">
          <span>= </span>
          <input spellcheck="false" data-bind="value: value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enable: enabled">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: enabled">
        </div>
      
        <div>
          <input readonly="true" spellcheck="false" tabindex="100" class="uriParameterLabel" data-bind="value: '{' + name + '}'">
          <span>= </span>
          <input spellcheck="false" data-bind="value: value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enable: enabled">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: enabled">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm learning to automate API testing and came across an element that don't have unique identifier as it is automatically getting its value from the endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Copy the same HTML code in text format and update the question with that.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to locate the *textbox* corresponding to `{userid}` field you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel']/div[contains(@data-bind, 'UriParameters')]/div//following::input[2]"))).click()
  #or
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel']/div[contains(@data-bind, 'UriParameters')]/div//following::input[2]"))).send_keys("Ice")
  ```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I apologize as I am very new at this. The {userid} is not clickable. I want to know how to locate/call the **textbox** for **userid and deviceid** for me to input data. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @Ice If you can confirm me the status whether the solution works or not I can explain you in details. Are you able to locate the `userid` field and perform your tasks?

Comment: @Ice Can you update the question with your current code trial _to locate the text box_ and the exception for further analysis?

Comment: I got it! I made a simple modification on your code from

 `userID = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel']/div[contains(@data-bind, 'UriParameters')]/div//following::input[2]")))` 

to 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel']/div[contains(@data-bind,'UriParameters')]/div//following::input[2]").click()`

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ice Your question was about **_locating the textbox_** but not **clicking** :) but you shouldn't drop the _WebDriverWait_ as the website is _ReactJS_ based. I will update your question as well as my answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks again!